# Efficiently calculate the statistics on a given metrics on a list of students

Tags: java, statistics

Student.java

```
public class Student{
    /*
    Metrics examples (out of 100):
    mathScore:98
    scienceScore:99
    englishScore:92
    */
    private Map<String, Double> metrics = new HashMap<>();

    public Double getMetric(final String metricName) {
     return metrics.get(metricName);
   }

}
```

Statistics

```
public enum Statistic {

     AVERAGE,
     MIN,
     MAX
}
```

Result

```
public class Result {
  private Statistic statistic;
  private double value;
  private String metric;
}
```

What's the most efficient way to build an engine that can perform requested statical analysis based on the requested metrics on a list of students

Here's an example:

Say I have a list of Students.

```
List<Student> students = [john, json, elliot, sarah, callie, matt, leigh]; //Assume each entry is an object
```

I also have list of metrics  I'm interested in

```
List<String> metrics  =["mathScore", "scienceScore"]; //Just an example. I can add additional metrics to this list or remove them.
```

And the statistics I want to perform

```
List<Statistic> stats = [MIN, MAX]; //Just an example. I can request additional operations if necessary.
```

Here's the signature of the method that needs to be efficiently built

```
public List<Result> calculate( List<String> requestedMetrics, List<Statistic> requestedStatistics, List<Student> students){

}
```

Here are my initial thoughts

1. Convert requestedMetrics and requestedStatistics to sets to
   eliminate duplicates.
2. Iterate through each metric. For each metric,
   iterate through each statistic and calculate it. Is there a better
   way? And how does one go about breaking down the implementation in
   to smaller functions etc. for a cleaner solution?
3. What about creating a cache (map) so that we don't need to reprocess 
   everything again and again?

Here's my current implementation

```
@Component
public class StatisticalAnalysis {

    @Override
    public List<Result> calculate(List<Student> students, List<String> metrics, List<Statistic> stats) {

        return analyze(new HashSet<>(students), new HashSet<>(metrics), new HashSet<>(stats));
    }

    public List<Result> analyze(HashSet<Student> students, HashSet<String> metrics, HashSet<Statistic> stats) {

        List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>(metrics.size());

        for (String metric : metrics) {
            for (Statistic stat : stats) {
               results.add(createResult(students, metric, stat ));
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    private Result createResult(HashSet<Student> students, String metric, Statistic stat) {

       return new Result(metric, stat, calcStatValue(students, metric, stat));

    }

    private double calcStatValue(HashSet<Student> students, String metric, Statistic stat) {


        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>(students.size());

        for(Student measurement: students){
            Double value = measurement.getMetric(metric);
            if(value!=null)
                values.add(value);
        }

        return performStatOperation(stat, values);

    }

    private double performStatOperation(Statistic stat, List<Double> values) {
        switch (stat) {
            case MIN:
                return Collections.min(values);
            case MAX:
                return Collections.max(values);
            case AVERAGE:
                return values.stream().mapToDouble(val -> val).average().orElse(0.0);
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Calculation of Statistic %s is currently unsupported", stat));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @dfhwze Removed it. One of the goals of the review is to see if there's another style that's more efficient.

Comment: @dfhwze I can't specifically think of individual algorithmic improvements. But there could be enhancements that I'm missing. Also is there an alternative design style and how does that compare? Is there a disadvantage to creating smaller functions? These are just a few examples. There could be other elements to review!

Comment: When you talk about the cache, do you mean that when a student's results get added, only a delta needs to be calculated to the existing statistics?

Comment: Yes. Saving the calculations for a list of users maybe? So that if the same request is repeated, it could be pulled form cache.

Comment: Shouldn't `List<Result> calculate` be `List<Result> result`?

Comment: It's hard to believe that this code works as expected. You cannot get any information from the `Student` class since the map of metrics is initially empty and not modifiable from outside the `Student` class.

Answer (score 2):

This can be vastly simplified using a handful of tricks from functional programming. Let's first consider the operations you want to perform, given a collection of students, metrics and stats.

1. Extract the metrics you're interested in from the students. 
   In SQL this would be equivalent to a `SELECT` clause.
2. Perform the calculations for each of the statistics you want on the metrics you obtained.
3. Return a `Result` for each combination of metrics and stats with the calculated value.

Right now performing the calculation is something that `calcStatValue` knows about. This makes it a bit annoying to add an additional statistic like MEDIAN, because you need to track down the switch-case statement.

To avoid this, the calculation should be the responsibility of the statistic itself. Given that you can have members on Enums, the following should work:

```java
public enum Statistic {
    MIN(values -> Collections.min(values)),
    MAX(values -> Collections.max(values)),
    AVERAGE(values -> values.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).average().orElse(0.0));

    private final Function<Collection<Double>, Double> aggregator;

    private Statistic(Function<Collection<Double>, Double> aggregator) {
        this.aggregator = aggregator;
    }

    public double performStatOperation(Collection<Double> values) {
        return aggregator.apply(values);
    }
}
```

The rest of my suggestions basically boils down to some minor changes:

- If you preinitialize the size of `results` in `analyze`, you should use the actual number of slots you'll be using with `new ArrayList<>(metrics.size() * stats.size())`.
- You don't gain significant benefits from converting the `List` parameters to `HashSet`s. If you want to force uniqueness in the implementation, you really should be communicating that in the public API of your class by only accepting Sets in the first place.
- `calcStatValue` can be simplified using streams:

  ```
  return stat.performStatOperation(students.stream()
    .map(s -> s.getMetric(metric))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
  ```
- A similar simplification applies to `analyze`, but I'll not write that out here.

Additional remarks:

- The `results.add([..])` line in `analyze` has inconsistent spacing at the parentheses.
- Using a specific collection implementation as API (i.e. `HashSet` as parameter) should be avoided.
- The domain model representation sucks. Representing a metric by a String is not a good idea (because tyops), and forcing each metric to be represented in a `double` is also bad (because non-numeric metrics are a thing). In addition your API currently does not have any way to perform aggregation and analysis operations that do not yield a single result (e.g. histogramming, tallying, ...)